# Dynamically Adding Labels to User Form = Blank UserForm

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to dynamically add buttons to the userform, but the userform just comes up blank. Ive simplified the essence of the code as much as possible for error checking (not that it's helped me)

```
Sub addLabel()
UserForm2.Show    
Dim theLabel As Label
Dim labelCounter As Integer

For labelCounter = 1 To 3
    Set Label = UserForm2.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "Test" & labelCounter, True)
    With theLabel
        .Caption = "Test" & labelCounter
        .Left = 10
        .Width = 50
        .Top = 10
    End With
End Sub
```

Is there any way of checking if the buttons have been added but are invisible? Or why they are not being added. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A few things:

1. You need to show your UserForm as `vbModeless` - else the  code stops on `UserForm2.Show`
2. You are creating an object called `Label` then using `With` on `theLabel`
3. You will then need to increment the position of your three labels to avoid overlap (which I have done using `Top`).

   ```
   Sub addLabel()
   UserForm2.Show vbModeless
   Dim theLabel As Object
   Dim labelCounter As Long

   For labelCounter = 1 To 3
       Set theLabel = UserForm2.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "Test" & labelCounter, True)
       With theLabel
           .Caption = "Test" & labelCounter
           .Left = 10
           .Width = 50
           .Top = 10 * labelCounter
       End With
   Next
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: Thankyou very much for the feedback. I copy and pasted your code directly into the UserForm2 module, press f5, the form loads, but is still completely blank. I even opened a brand new work book, repeated the above steps, saved the new workbook and press run and still just a blank userform. Is there potentially a setting that i must change or something external to the code, as your code looks like it does exactly what i wanted it to do, but it doesnt :S Thanks again!

Comment: OMG! Of Course! Thankyou so much. This is why i love this site. You are a good person!

Answer (score 0):

After the `end with` statement, add:

```
userform1.show
```

One more correction:

```
.top = 10*labelcounter+10
```

Answer (score -4):

try below code

```
Set theLabel = UserForm2.Designer.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "Test1", True)
```

Comment: Use of Designer is lazy and dangerous in this instance.  It shows a lack of understanding of the Forms Object and how to interact with them